# Jammit package_assets destroys things

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yui-compressor, jammit

I am using the `Jammit` gem to aggregate CSS and Javascript files into single resources for faster download. Using YUI compression, I assembled a large number of scripts and stylesheets into the `assets.yml` config file and everything gets loaded correctly in the development environment.

However, when I specify `package_assets: always` in the `assets.yml` file to enforce asset packaging under development, then suddenly multiple errors occur and the Web page fails to load properly.

As the order of the includes is correct, I do not understand what else could have gone wrong... Is it possible that Jammit reorders or damages the code of packaged Javascript files? Could it be that including already minified files into `assets.yml` causes problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which compression are you using?

i've used the YUI and everything worked great.

maybe you've got a previously minified js file and that compression is breaking it?

Comment: I also used YUI. But yes, I have several previously minified JS files... only I do not see any reason why that should break the code. Minifying a file may not improve things, but it definitely should not destroy anything...

Comment: i agree with you, but also don't know the algorithm behind it